# What happens when a script loads a single library in a continuous loop?

Tags: performance, codeigniter, ram

I've been learning programming for some time now. PHP, Javascript etc and i'm not an expert yet. But i know about plugins and libraries, what they do and how they're used.

Now i know that a library once loaded can be used repetitively in code. But what if the structure of my code requires me to load a library in a continuous loop, say 100,000 times.

What impact could this have on the server hosting my application if any?

Especially in terms of memory and process consumption etc.....

Eg. Sending emails using codeigniter will require;

```
function send_mail(){
   $this->load->library('email');

   $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
   $this->email->to('someone@example.com');
   $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
   $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

   $this->email->subject('Email Test');
   $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
}
```

What if i need to call this function 100,000 times for a bulk email service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code there is no impact on memory. Libraries (classes) in CodeIgniter are "singletons", meaning that once the library is loaded any additional attempts to load the same library will simply return the instance created the first time `load` was called. In other words, there will be only one instance created of any library loaded.

There is a some impact on processing as the call to `$this->load->library('email');` will run code to determine that `email` is already loaded. It isn't a lot of code but it adds up inside a loop and is completely unnecessary.

Assuming that `function send_mail(){` is part of a class (e.g. a controller) then you could eliminate the extra processing by loading the `email` library in the constructor of the library.

Here is an example controller.

```
class App_emailer extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->library('email');
    }

    public function send_mail()
    {
        $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to('someone@example.com');
        $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
        $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

        $this->email->send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Load the library in the construct class 
or
2.Autoload the library in config/autoload.php: the line

```
$autoload['libraries']=array('email');
```